# Lightning community has no Reports tab like a Tabs + VF community has?

Tags: reporting, lightning-community, reports-folder

We want to convert an existing Tabs + VF community to a Lightning community (using Customer Account Portal template).  The users are all Customer Community Plus users.

In the Tabs + VF community, the users are able to see the Reports tab and can see a complete list of reports and of report folders they have permissions to.

However, we cannot find any way in the Lightning Community Builder to expose a Reports tab.

**Can anyone confirm that there is no equivalent Reports tab functionality in any Lightning community template?**

I'm not asking about a specific report or dashboard.  I know that a single report or dashboard can be presented in a component.  The community user needs to see the complete list of reports and folders, just like on the reports tab in Tabs community.

Comment: Well, I added reports tab in the community recently, I followed this step.

click on nav bar-> Navigation Menu -> Add Menu Item -> Provide Name and From Type Select Sobject. -> from Object Type select Report. Publish

Comment: @PranayJaiswal so simple!  I was looking only at the left sidebar of the builder and didn't even think to click on the nav bar for options.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I added reports tab in the community recently, I followed the below step.

Click on nav bar-> Navigation Menu -> Add Menu Item -> Provide Name and From Type Select Sobject. -> From Sobject select Report. Publish

Bam done.

Comment: +1. In addition to this, we need to give the `Run Report` permission to the users from the profile/permission set.